# ¿Cómo hacer una atar un case a mi sentencia usando PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

quien pueda darme una recomendación se lo agradeceria

He realizado esta consulta

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
WHEN PPL.TIPO = '1' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTAL
-
SUM(CASE
WHEN PPL.TIPO = '2' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTAL,
SUM(CASE
WHEN PPL.TIPO = '1' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTAL,
SUM(CASE
WHEN PPL.TIPO = '2' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTAL
FROM DETALLE PP
INNER JOIN PRODUCTO  PPL ON
PP.ID= PPL.ID
AND PP.CODIGO = PPL.CODIGO
AND PP.NRO_PROD= PPL.NRO_PROD
```

Basicamente necesito hacer la suma del total de tipo = '1'
menos la suma del total de tipo = '2' y en las demás solo hacer sumas de tipo case.

Pero al ejecutar la sentencia en Oracle SQL Developer
me despliega el siguiente error:

*ORA-00923: palabra clave FROM no encontrada donde se esperaba
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error en la línea: 44, columna: 1*

Comment: Primero prueba ejecutar las tres sentencias por separado para confirmar que funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Si se ejecutan bien por separado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice algunas pruebas para encontrar el problema y al parecer está en el alias del primer `SUM`.
Pues el alias es por la diferencia.
Yo lo puse así para que se note:
La diferencia de los dos primeros `SUM` es ***DIFERENCIA***.
Luego los alias de los `SUM` siguientes son ***TOTTIPO1*** y ***TOTTIPO2***.
Debería funcionarte.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PPL.TIPO = '1' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) - SUM(CASE WHEN PPL.TIPO = '2' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS DIFERENCIA,
SUM(CASE WHEN PPL.TIPO = '1' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTTIPO1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN PPL.TIPO = '2' THEN PPL.CANTIDAD*PPL.PRECIO END) AS TOTTIPO2
FROM DETALLE PP
INNER JOIN PRODUCTO  PPL ON
PP.ID= PPL.ID
AND PP.CODIGO = PPL.CODIGO
AND PP.NRO_PROD= PPL.NRO_PROD
```

Comment: Gracias al final al final hice un union xD

Comment: Y yo recalentando mi servidor ;D